# Custom Event For Custom JQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

I made this jQuery plugin called **removable** when you click the objects button it slides up and should trigger a custom event like **onDone**.

Here's what I did (The codeing format is based on jQuery's http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring):

```
init: function(){
    return this.each(function(){
        $('a', this).click(function(){
            $(this).parent().slideUp(function(){

                    // Somehow trigger the onDone method

            })
        });
    })
},
onDone: function(){
    // Default action
},
```

and this is what I've done when calling the plugin

```
   $('li').removable({
        onDone: function(){
          // Overwrite default action
        },
    })
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to call it at the end of the animation, just pass it as the second argument to slideUp or even just call it with $(foo).MyPlugin.onDone() inside the callback function.

otherwise look at [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) and [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) jQuery functions - you can use any string you want for those event types so you can trigger and bind a MyPluginDone event

EDIT: based on comments you want something simpler -

As it states in the article you quoted, the best way to provide override-able defaults to options is to have your plugin accept an `options`  object, then to get the combined defaults+overrides you do:

```
var combinedOpts = $.extend({},defaults,overrides);
```

and get all the values to use from there...

Comment: My objective is to overwrite the default "onDone" behaviour when calling my plugin. So each object using the plugin can have some custom actions when somthing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
(function($){
jQuery.fn.extend({
    removable: function(options) {
        var defaults = {  
             onDone: function(){alert('default action');}
        };  
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);  
        return this.each(function() {   
            $('a', this).click(function(){
                 $(this).parent().slideUp(function(){
                 options.onDone.call();
            });
        });
});
    }
});
  })(jQuery);

  $('li').removable({
    onDone: function(){
      alert('Overwrite default action');
    },
})
```